# Получение файла из удалённого репозитория

Tags: git

Всем привет. В локальном репозитории был удалён файл, пытаюсь получить его из удалённого командами git fetch origin master, а потом git pull origin master, но он так и не появляется. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы восстановить файл из произвольной ветки (в т.ч. удалённой) выполните команду **checkout**.

```
git checkout origin/master имя_файла
```